# Flexslider image very slight erroneous movement in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, flexslider

I am using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) but I've encountered some kind of a problem.

It's actually visible in the [demo](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/flexslider-demo/). This only happens in Firefox, or at least it doesn't appear in IE9 or Chrome. When you re-size the browser to about 400-500px wide and switch between the last two images ( the hill and the bird ), if you look carefully you can see that the images actually jump up and down slightly by about a pixel when they switch. *Actually you might need more than one attempt at resizing the window to replicate this behaviour it may not always show, but it does at least 50% of the time.*

This is very tiny I know but when I was doing a 1200px wide slider it was very noticeable. I spend hours tracing the problem until I noticed it was actually inherent.

However what I discovered was that when the images have a caption ( a `<p>` tag is used ) then they don't exhibit this behaviour. You can verify this using firebug.

My question is this: Does anyone know what the p tag would be doing to prevent this behaviour. It's great to be able to force it to work but I want to avoid using a non semantic empty paragraph tag in the markup if I can avoid it.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it in firefox. Which version are you using?

Comment: version 13 .. it's very hard to see - only visible on the last 2 images. I will try a different computer here

Comment: @Andy actually I must confess I tried Firefox on my old desktop and and I actually couldn't replicate it there myself. So it looks like it might be a hardware problem, maybe it's a FF plugin. Any thoughts on whether to delete this question or not?

Comment: Well in my faultfinding I've come to the conclusion that the problem is **not** on my computer as when I downloaded the package and run the demo on my desktop machine, I found the same problem; not sure why it didn't show on the online demo on that computer, but it's easier to see with the bigger images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following code to the css. I don't understand why but it seems to need something either outside of the `<li>` tags (or having height inside them?) for it to remain steady. Changing list-style to disc also works, but that won't look good.

```
.slides li:after {
content: ".";
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:-1000;
}
```

EDIT: 
Actually that code works slightly better if `top:0` is replaced by `bottom:0` as the strange effect comes back when the slider is partially off screen otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem. Mac OS 10.7.4, Firefox 15.0.1 and also 13.something (I think it was 13.0.1). Your solution worked!